# Bootstrap-select not show correctly the last option element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I use Bootstrap-select plugin for select input elements. The problem is that even the list of options is relatively small, when I have to pick the last element, it shows in half. The last element and form itself is always cut at the end.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City:</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker city" data-live-search="true" name="city">
    <option value="">--- Select all ---</option>
    <option data-th-each="city : ${cities}" data-th-value="${city}" data-th-text="${city}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

PS - the code above is written for Thymeleaf template engine (but I think that it is not important part )

Comment: Your screenshot is good, but to help solve this issue it's always best if you provide code so we can take a look ourselves :)

Comment: Done  I edited the post :)

Comment: You can set data-size attribute in your select tag to display number of options and then scroll bar.

Comment: Is that a text input at the top of the options? (usually that would be included as a live text filter of the select options)  - how is that inserted - I would seem that the scroll bar for the options is below it - meaning that it is pushing the options down and possibly affecting the layout of the options list - to the point of cutting off the last option - try removing the text inut and see if that returns the normal layout of the slect options.

Comment: Kishan same situation with data-size .. attr.
@gavgrif - This text input is added from bootstrap-select with attribute - data-live-search="true". So it is not added from me. It part of bootstrap-select functionality.

other ideas ?

Comment: are you sure you are using it correctly? I just looked at the documentation and the example of the live search select is using a ul / li structure rather than a select / option structure (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search)

Comment: If you have applied any css like max-height to your select tag then remove that, I think that should be issue.Check which css applied to that select tag.

Comment: The problem seems to get from this data-live-search="true".
When i removed it, everything works, but i don't have search :( So.. how to put this search , without to break the form

Comment: @gavgrif the example of live search is used exactly with option/select :) 

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1590), the solution is to add this css:

```
   span.form-control {
     height: 0px;
   }
   .dropdown-menu.open {
     max-height: none !important;
   }
```

But upgrading to the latest release (1.13.5 at this moment) also solves the issue